# What happens when someone goes to the root URL in WordPress Multisite?

Tags: multisite, urls

I'm going to set up a multisite for www.company.com/uk  and www.company.com/usa.  What will the browser show if someone just puts in www.company.com (which is the current widely used URL)?

Answer (score 2):

The root URL in WordPress Multisite loads the main site for the network - your primary site.